# c# .net and win2012 firewall

Tags: c#, firewall

I'm not that advanced with C# and need some assistance compiling a code. Honestly it's first time I'm doing that. I have a code that is aimed to automatically block rdp bruteforce. 
Here is acode I'm trying to compile: https://pastebin.com/CJEapWyi

I've got problems interacting with firewall api. 
In the internet people say I have to add reference to FirewallAPI.dll and I'm compiling code using following CLI:

```
    c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>csc.exe /r:"c:\windows\system32\FirewallApi.dll" c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\rdpbrute.cs
```

and it says:

error CS0006: Metadata file 'FirewallApi.dll' could not be found

Is there any way to compile a program that interacts with firewall using this compiler or I have to install visual studio?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Paste your code directly into the question.  Don't rely on pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of referencing **c:\windows\system32\FirewallApi.dll** you should first create COM interop library **Interop.FirewallApi.dll** and then add reference to it.

Interop library can be created with use of [tlbimp.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-generate-interop-assemblies-from-type-libraries) tool that is part of Visual Studio installation. A more simple approach is to use **Add reference** feature inside of VS (just select c:\windows\system32\FirewallApi.dll and interop library will be created automatically).

So you have to install VS as you suggested.